# Modify LED headlight with buck converter, to make it dimmable

Tags: led, buck, dimmer

[image][image][image][image]

[image]

I only know enough in electronics to be dangerous.

Is there a way to modify this LED board to make it have a dimmable setting?

I was hoping to just remove a resistor and replace it with a variable or a tiny switch to a different resistor.

The headlight is being used on a bike, and it is far too bright for oncoming riders, but I want to use the bright setting in dark woods. It is like high-beams on a car.

Apparently it is a buck converter that takes about 6 to 80 volts. I am only using 12V.

Markings on the IC should be 76CCT C02A 025458

Comment: That makes it more challenging. Play aroubd with the value of the resistor that has ‘752’ on it. That translates to 7500 Ohms (7.5k). Try 10k

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a natlinear LN2576 led driver. http://www.natlinear.com/uploadfiles/2014/LN/LN2576_C.pdf and http://www.natlinear.com/uploadfiles/2014/LN/LN2576.pdf

[image]

Two options are changing the sense resistor or taking advantage of the mode feature.

The led current is regulated by the sense resistor CS, connected between pin 5 and ground. Likely R11 0.180 Ohms. Led current = Voltage CS / CS. Voltage CS is around 0.2V, so `Iled = 0.2V / 0.180` the led current should be about 1.11 Amps. You could confirm with a multimeter current mode. You can replace it with a 0.3 ohm resistor for 0.66 Amps. Roughly half the current and thus light output (but it's not linear).

The Mode function is a built in 50% dim feature. If the mode pin is floating or pulled to ground, the led brightness is 100%. If you pull it to VDD (NOT VCC or DRV!) Then the led brightness is dropped to 50% of what it should be. The mode pin is pin 5. VDD is pin 2, which is clamped to 8V. Check with a multimeter.

If 50% is good enough, see where pin 5 is connected. It may be tied to ground or it may go to one of those unused resistor or diode pads. In The up-close picture with the 76cct label, you can clearly see that a trace exists. It it's tied to ground, you can cut the trace. If it goes to an unused pad and no where else, you can use that to solder to. Then add a SPST switch between it and pin 2. That's your low/high beam switch

Comment: Since the trim pot almost but didn't work, I may need to go this route, If I can figure this out. Maybe I will use a magnetic switch and use a tiny magnet as a high beam key or something.

It seems like the board is setup for a 2nd resistor value... will this be needed to use the 50%?

Comment: @ron the board looks like it has other options like a second set of leds or something off board. Based on VL at the bottom and the leds being labeled d6-d10 instead of d1 etc. If you did a full schematic which should be easy enough with a board this simple we could tell if that missing resistor lead to anything. But no, according to the datasheet you should be able to tie it directly to VCC and be fine. If you are concerned than a 10k ish resistor should be fine enough.

Comment: Added another image above, the green schematic found via google.

This makes me think the mode requires use of the VL (Low Voltage) going through the diode and resistor(s). They seem to be wired just like this.

Comment: @ron could be for use with a second power supply, but seems unnecessary. The two diodes at hv and lv create a diode or power selection. That schematic is also one resistor short. The board has 4 resistors present.

Answer (score 0):

The brightness of the light is set by the value of R11.  Put a small value potentiometer (~10 ohm) in series with it and you can dim the light as much as you want.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to do. There are 2 Resistors R1 and R11, was not sure which to experiment with first.

Comment: R11 looks like the sense resistor with a value of 0.18 Ohm.

Comment: @RonGardner You can tell it is R11 because the value of R1 is huge, meaning if it was in series with the LEDs they would barely light up at all.

Comment: R1 seems to be the series resistor for the built in 8V zener regulator for the IC power input. The IC runs at 8V max.

Comment: UPDATE:

Confirming that Changing the R11 resistance, changed the LED brightness. 
I soldered in a trim dial, and it allowed me to change LED brightness. However, the lowest resistance trim dial I found was not low enough, at 8 to 1k ohm. 
The board seems to need closer to 0-10 ohm to go from full bright to off.
I guess I need a tinier trim pot... but wont be able to mount those the way I wanted.

Comment: @RonGardner if you make the resistor 5000x bigger the light gets 5000x less current. I recommended a 10ohm pot so that you could dim up to 50x.